# Removing a row in mySQl based on the substring of a field value?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, where-clause, sql-delete

I've got a table with 14,000,000 (14 million) rows. I've just realised I can cut this number down significantly by removing rows where a certain field's 1st and 2nd characters are either 23,24,25,54,55, or 56.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE Substring of field in column LIKE 24 OR 25 OR 26.... Etc
```

Thanks,

LazyTotoro :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure of which strings to look for, you can just do this:

```
delete
from tablename
where left(fieldname,2) in ('23','24','25','54','55','56')
```

`left` provides a convenient solution since you are looking for the first 2 characters. If you wanted to get a substring between the ends, you could use `substring` with the syntax `substring(fieldname, startingposition, length)`.

Comment: So just to clarify: If 'LEFT(fieldname,2)' had the value of 'pokemon', 'po' would be what was selected?

Comment: Exactly - it's the left most n characters.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the SUBSTRING() function.

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

For example, if you use SUBTRING(str, 1, 2) it will return 2 characters starting from the first position in the string, so if you have SUBSTRING("123456", 1, 2), it will return "12".

So you would have:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE SUBSTRING(field, 1, 2) IN (24,25,26)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides the [`SUBSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function.